# Clojure assoc vector behaviour

Tags: clojure

Clojure `assoc` applied to vector seems have inconsistent behaviour

When index is present in vector, assoc replace the value

```
(assoc [1 2 3 4 5] 3 42) => [1 2 3 42 5]
```

When index is next to last one, the vector grows (`conj` equivalent)

```
(assoc [1 2 3 4 5] 5 42) => [1 2 3 4 5 42])
```

Otherwise `IndexOutOfBoundsExcpetion` is thrown

though it useful in some cases like `reduce assoc`, this may lead to subtle bugs in a program

Is it expected behaviour or probably bug in assoc for vector?

Comment: true, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expected. See the docstring for `assoc`, especially the last note regarding the `index` argument.

This is described at the top of p. 101 of *Clojure Programming*.